# How can I extract the link to the image here?

Tags: python, html, image, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using BS4 to scrape webpages for article titles, author names, and links to their cover images.

This is the HTML tag I found for the image of a specific article:

```
<img src="https://cdn.theatlantic.com/thumbor/lYaNkJfiPr8_Jp5Pj5ikj94GJgQ=/183x0:2000x1125/210x130/media/img/2021/06/WEL_Tiffany_KodakOpenerAlt-1/original.jpg" alt="Photo collage on a yellow background" loading="lazy" class="Image_root__J8Wlz Image_lazy__1w_jB Image_loaded__3uNg2 LandingRiver_image__1ZCUb" width="210" height="130" srcset="https://cdn.theatlantic.com/thumbor/lYaNkJfiPr8_Jp5Pj5ikj94GJgQ=/183x0:2000x1125/210x130/media/img/2021/06/WEL_Tiffany_KodakOpenerAlt-1/original.jpg, https://cdn.theatlantic.com/thumbor/NL-ZZp6sHiX_1WX2bn9f9o1WWjk=/183x0:2000x1125/420x260/media/img/2021/06/WEL_Tiffany_KodakOpenerAlt-1/original.jpg 2x">
```

This is the code I'm using to get the image URL:

```
cover_image = card.find('img')['src']
```

However, instead of

```
"https://cdn.theatlantic.com/thumbor/lYaNkJfiPr8_Jp5Pj5ikj94GJgQ=/183x0:2000x1125/210x130/media/img/2021/06/WEL_Tiffany_KodakOpenerAlt-1/original.jpg"
```

it keeps returning

```
data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 210 130' /%3E
```

I've also tried getting the 'srcset' part of the tag but that doesn't even show up in the code.

What can I do in such cases?

Comment: there is multiple `img` tag in a html, find gives you the first match, try with `class_="Image_root__J8Wlz Image_lazy__1w_jB Image_loaded__3uNg2 LandingRiver_image__1ZCUb"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try selecting using the class name as sugggested by [Epis95](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6660638/epsi95):

```py
cover_image = card.find('img',class_ = "Image_root__J8Wlz Image_lazy__1w_jB Image_loaded__3uNg2 LandingRiver_image__1ZCUb")['src']

# and if you want the best image quality you could do

# firstly get the srcset
cover_image = card.find('img',class_ = "Image_root__J8Wlz Image_lazy__1w_jB Image_loaded__3uNg2 LandingRiver_image__1ZCUb")['srcset']

# as srcset is a string but the links are seperated using ',' you could split it on the same
cover_image = cover_image.split(',')

# after splitting the best image quality lik is the last one so get the last element of the new list that you have after splitting
cover_image = cover_image[-1]

# you now have a string with 2x as the unwanted part at the last and you could remove that using the slice operation
cover_image = cover_image[:-2]    # slice it upto the third last characterto chop off '2x'

# now you have a string with leading and trailing spaces so strip it to remove any leading or trailing spaces
cover_image = cover_image.strip()
print(cover_image)    # this is the best quality image you can get
```

###### Output:

```py
https://cdn.theatlantic.com/thumbor/NL-ZZp6sHiX_1WX2bn9f9o1WWjk=/183x0:2000x1125/420x260/media/img/2021/06/WEL_Tiffany_KodakOpenerAlt-1/original.jpg
```